# Why gettype for two different objects of same type has same reference

Tags: c#

```
public class Test
{
    class A
    {
        public int i;
        public A(int x)
        {
            i = x;
        }
        public A()
        {

        }
        public override bool Equals(Object obj)
        {
            A a = (A)obj;
            if (this.i == a.i)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }        
    }
    static void Main()

    {
        A a = new A(1);
        A b = new A();
        Type t =typeof(A);
        Type t1 = b.GetType();
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(t,t1));
    }
}
```

This returns true(that implies that they have same reference)just like string concepts strings returns true as they have interned pool what does this have.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Its true because they are the same type...

Comment: It's the same type, what is the question here?

Comment: @musefan - He's asking why the two methods that each return an instance of `Type` are returning the **same instance** of `Type`.

Comment: As a courteous guest on the C# tag, this is a nice feature: C# is not creating a whole bunch of `Type` objects with the same contents. Seems pretty sensible to me. I like the way you've verified that.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Perhaps you should re-write the question for him then

Comment: @musefan - I think that the question was pretty straightforward. :-)

Comment: Indeed, straightforward and clear with example code to boot - I don't understand the downvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns the same instance because it is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) to so:

> For two objects `x` and `y` that have identical runtime types, `Object.ReferenceEquals(x.GetType(),y.GetType())` returns **true**.

The exact implementation details on how they implemented this is undocumented.

If your question is really "how did they implement this so that it always returns the same instance" then *that* part is **not** documented.

I would assume it is *relatively* safe to say they have a lookup data structure containing these objects but *exactly* how they did this, that is undocumented.

Comment: Strings has intern pool for making two references same if they have equal string value. Does the type has something like that is what I'm asking

Comment: It must have, otherwise they would've returned different instances each time. But understand that you're asking about undocumented implementation details, I cannot tell you how this is implemented without looking at the code and even if I did, there's no guarantee that the exact current implementation is there in the next .NET version.